# Variation of the Principle of Mathematical Induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Every version of weak mathematical induction I have seen is equivalent to the following statement.
Let ${n_0}$ be some integer such that

1. P(n) is some predicate defined for all integers greater than or equal to ${n_0}$
2. ${n_0}$ ${\in}$ S (where S is the truth set of P)
3. ${\forall} n {\geq}$ ${n_0}$, $( P(n) = T {\rightarrow} P(n+1) = T )$
   Then S is the set all the integers greater than or equal to ${n_0}$.

Recently, though I came across a use of weak induction which does not fit this form, and I was wondering how its use is justified. When you are proving that the Euclidean algorithm yields the gcd of any two natural numbers *a* and *b*, there is a step where you have to prove the last non-zero remainder, which we'll denote by ${r_n}$, divides all of the other remainders and divisors. The way I have seen this done is to use induction to show that ${r_n}$ divides $r_{n-k}$ for k=0,1,...,n-1. The predicate here would then be $P(k): {r_n}|r_{n-k}$.

The problem is that the truth set for P is a subset of the integers, which is bounded below, but *also* has an upper bound. This seems different to me than what we normally do in induction, where we are proving a statement is true for an infinite chain of integers. So I am wondering how one shows that (what I understand to be) the standard form of induction can be used in a context like this. It almost seems that since the process involves a finite number of steps, induction is not even required. I thought about the fact that maybe the inductive hypothesis is that the statement holds for any natural numbers $a$ and $b$ requiring n steps and what we are really proving is that this implies it holds for any $a'$ and $b'$ requiring $(n+1)$ steps, but my professor says this is not what the proof is doing.
Thank you

Comment: Let $P(k) = (k > n) \vee (r_n \mid r_{n-k})$.

Comment: Or you could define $r_k=0$ when $k<0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer like this idea, although I worry a tad about the fact that the division statement will not be defined for k>(n-1), but I think that can be fixed up fix up by replacing the divisibility statement after the OR by an implication like (k<n implies r_n divides r_(n-k). Thanks! That is very clever!!

Comment: @MattBrenneman Lazy evaluation, $\mathrm{True}\; \lor \perp = \mathrm{True}$ ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually you were correct b/c the way the proof is done, the truth set starts at k=0 (not n). So when 0 ${\leq}$ k < n, the 2nd statement in the OR statement (regarding divisibility) is true and when k ${\geq}$ n, the first statement in the OR statement is true (if you just change the greater than to greater than or equal to).

Comment: @MattBrenneman For future reference, you should not include just single terms in LaTeX markup delimiters: put the whole equation in one. In other words, `$a + b = c$` rather than `$a$+$b$=$c$`. This ensures consistent formatting. To achieve line breaks, simply hit enter twice; StackExchange does not recognize HTML markup.